# How to add culture invariant info in timestamp in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, insert-query

How to add culture invariant info while adding timestamp in Postgresql database ?

**Create table query:**

```
CREATE TABLE Table1(Id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,CreatedDate TIMESTAMP);
```

**Insert query:**

```
insert into Table1 (CreatedDate)
   values (convert(TIMESTAMP,'18-06-12 10:34:09 PM',112));
```

I am getting below error while executing query in postgresql database.

```
column "timestamp" does not exist
```

Is this right way to insert timestamp into column ?

Comment: Can you comment what does your `112` mean?

Comment: CultureInfo("en-us") format.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are thinking about this backwards.  You don't add culture invariant info to a timestamp.  You format the timestamp using it (see `to_char`) or you use it to parse a timestamp (see the `datestyle` config option).

To insert a timestamp just insert it, and set your datestyle appropriately and then cast it to timestamp.  So if this is always US, then:

but in your case, I think something is wrong in your example because:

```
SELECT '18-06-12 10:34:09 PM'::timestamp;
```

works because 2018 is a valid year but if I first `SET DATESTYLE = 'US';` then I get an error because 18 is not a valid month.

Answer (score 1):

As I found out, you have to use `ADD TIME ZONE` like

```
(to_timestamp('18-06-12 10:34:09 PM', 'yy-MM-dd') AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles')
```

P.S. `America/Los_Angeles` it is just an example